# Can I say, ‘The boat had slowed down much.’?

Tags: grammar

1. Can I say, ‘The boat had slowed down much.’ ?
2. Can I say, ‘The boat had slowed down very much.’ ?

Comment: More usually: "The boat had slowed right down." It is still moving, but slowly.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am curious about whether I can add ‘much’ or ‘very much’ in the end of the sentence.

Comment: It is grammatical but clumsy, so I provided another way to say it.

Comment: @WeatherVane What is the difference between ‘right down’ and ‘down’ ?

Comment: When the boat has "slowed right down", that is a lot more slowly than when it "slowed down", or "slowed".

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "The boat had slowed down a lot" or "The boat had slowed down a great deal."

Comment: @Robusto Why can not use much instead of a lot?

Comment: You can, it just sounds awkward. It's the kind of thing a non-native speaker might say.

Comment: Both sentences are valid, but the first is mildly archaic.

Comment: @AntonSherwood It's okay that both are right, for me.